# .dir-locals.el isn't recognized

Tags: customize, compilation, file-local-variables

I am working on a project that includes some configuration in `.dir-locals.el`:

```
((c++-mode
  . ((compile-command . "cd ../../\; ./build.sh"))))
```

This gets picked up just fine for me and sets the compile command. A teammate's emacs doesn't seem to recognize the file. `.dir-locals.el` is present, but doesn't set the compile command (still defaults to `make -k`).

Evaluating `(dir-locals-find-file "Foo.h")` in `*scratch*` returns `.../project/src` on my system (which is the folder where `.dir-locals.el` is located), but returns `nil` for the teammate.

How do I troubleshoot this? Everything I can find in the documentation seems to assume that `.dir-locals.el` will get picked up if it's present.

Comment: Is your teammate using Tramp to edit the code on a remote machine? That's the only case I can think of where `.dir-locals.el` isn't picked up... Also, are you both running the same Emacs version?

Comment: @legoscia: Not familiar with the details of .dir-locals.el functionality, but couldn't access permission of the file come into play?

Comment: `.dir-locals.el` is part of a svn repository that is checked out on to his machine, so he has local read access to the file

Comment: He'll need to start with emacs -Q and figure out what's breaking.

Comment: If it doesn't work with -Q, another thing to check is that he's running a sufficiently new version of Emacs.